# Failing video Upload to youtube from ios app

Tags: ios, ipad, youtube, gdata-api

I am trying to upload video to Youtube using GData static library from an ipad app it is working fine if I upload from the same location where the Youtube account is being created but if the location is changed the upload from the app fails and when I log in via the website it displays a message: 
**Some One tried to Login in your account. Is that you?**

I have used client login authentication in my app.